# How to repair Visual Studio 2010 after broken installation of Async CTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I try to install the Async CTP for Visual Studio 2010 the installer fails.

I got the same problem **bob mujica** described in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/2b816f97-ba1a-4342-824f-07c53f946b57.

Now Visual Studio doesn't work at all. I don't care about having CTP, I just want Visual Studio back. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian,

I know it won't help in this scenario but a little advice for the future that could save a lot of heartache. for the past 7-8 years, i've got into a disciplined habit of making a fresh backup (ghost) of my program partition (genarally the c:\ drive in my case) everytime i add a new program feature (other than service packs etc) to my installation. This basically means that should something 'not work' after installing, I can simply restore the ghost image over the top, rather than spend hours trying to figure why.

As i said, may not help this time but is a good discipline to work towards in the future.

Comment: Wow, you clone the drive when you install software programs, but *not service packs*? I'd do that exactly the other way round! I see things break *way* more often when service packs are applied than when applications are installed.

Comment: this is what i love really, is the diversity of experience on these things. i've never (toucing invisible wood) had any issue with sps.that said, maybe i've just been lucky... i'll bear your thoughts in mind tho' as maybe i'm being too lax on luck!! :-)

Comment: I think things have gotten much better in recent years with applying SPs. I don't think I've had a real problem in a very long time, come to think of it. But I do remember back in the days of NT 4, service packs were a bit of a gamble, and I haven't lost the habit. Just a day or so ago, I noticed Windows Update was reporting SP 1 for Server 2008 R2, and I haven't downloaded it yet because I'm not sure it will play nicely with my system.

Comment: cody - i 'hate' you :-), i'm now going to ramp up my ghosting to include sps as the server 2008 r2 got me thinking !!

Comment: i am amazed then no one upvote this question. please show me the way you use for ghost.

Comment: ian - i actually use a product called partition manager: http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/features.html (but i referenced norton ghost for familiarity purposes). however, norton ghost is essentially the same. details here: http://uk.norton.com/ghost/

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to install a fresh copy of Visual Studio, or perhaps to copy files from a fresh installation to overwrite any updated libraries. Assuming that you have the installation media you could also try to repair the installation from Control Panel -> Programs (Add/Remove Programs if you're still on XP).

From the linked post it sounds like either (a) a library file has been overwritten with an incompatible version or (b) a library file is referenced but not found on the system. (a) likely can be fixed by trying any of the above. (b) most likely requires VS to be removed and reinstalled from scratch. If you have a second machine around, you could try installing VS on that and dump or record the relevant registry changes and compare it with the faulty installation, but it might be faster just to reinstall.