# Visual Studio 2022 randomly started freezing my system

Tags: visual-studio, crash, visual-studio-2022

I've been working with Visual Studio 2022 for a couple of months now, and I've used previous versions for years without any problems.

Today I copied a piece of code to rearrange it, saved right after and the program froze so bad I had to restart my whole system.

Ever since this happened I cant use the software, any time I try to do so it completely freezes my system after a couple of minutes, no matter which of my solutions I open or if I create a new one. I've also noticed it being much slower than it used to be.

I also don't use any extensions besides a color pack.

I use VS Code on the side as well, I don't experience any problems with it, I also doubt that my system is out of memory as I usually have 20+gbs of ram available.

Should I just reinstall Visual Studio completely? I really cant wrap my head around some corrupted files causing so much trouble.

Comment: A reinstall would be a simple thing to try to see if it resolves.  I think you can also run a repair through the Visual Studio Installer, but if not, I'd reinstall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repair Visual Studio 2010 after broken installation of Async CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131295/how-to-repair-visual-studio-2010-after-broken-installation-of-async-ctp)